# PHPMailer doesn't load HTML email with attachment on iPhone

Tags: phpmailer, html-email

I'm using PHPMailer to send an HTML email when someone requests a brochure from a website.

My issue is that when I send the email without the attachment the email opens and displays the HTML email correctly. As soon as I add the attachment it doesn't load the HTML email and just shows text. NB: I haven't uploaded any code as the email itself sends with or without the attachment, so didn't think you guys would need it.

So:

1) Email sends OK with or without the attachment
2) With the attachment, it arrives (with the attachment) but doesn't show HTML email
3) Without the attachment the HTML is displayed correctly.

This specifically relates to an iPhone and it asks me to download the remainder of the email.

I know this should work OK as I know a competitors website that uses the exact same process and their email loads perfect everytime!

Any help would be useful.

Comment: I would guess that this is down to message size - When you have the attachment, it's crossing some threshold that means mail won't/can't render it reasonably. I don't know what the size threshold is for iPhone mail. Probably the best thing to do is compare the raw message source from the two and see what the differences in message size and structure are.

Comment: Hi #Synchro that shouldn't be a problem. the attachment is 4.4mb whereas the competitions is actually 8.4mb and theirs goes through perfectly fine.  I'm left scratching my head here!

Comment: If you compare the raw messages side by side, does yours look significantly different before it gets to the attachment MIME section? For example, if yours has attachments before the HTML part, it may be missing the HTML part if it's only partially downloaded.

Comment: I'll tell you what I have noticed is that when I attach the PDF the encoding starts putting in some strange characters such as 3D and 09!

Comment: Nothing strange about them - that's normal quoted-printable encoding. That said, adding an attachment should have no bearing on that; the attachment itself should be using base64. I think it might help to post your code.